# Error with align environment in LaTeX

Tags: align

I have the following math equation in latex which I want to be aligned, but when I compile the code I get no result neither error message. Can someone help me fix the code.

```
\begin{align}
 \alpha &= \frac{p(θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T})}{p(θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*})}{q(θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t})}\\
    &=  \frac{p(θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T})}{p(θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}{q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})}\frac{q(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T}^{t},θ^{t})}{q(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T}^{*},θ^{*})}\\
    &= \frac{p(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T},θ^{*})}{p(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T},θ^{t})}\frac{p(\theta^{*}|y_{1:T})}{p(\theta^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}{q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})}\frac{q(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T}^{t},θ^{t})}{q(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T}^{*},θ^{*})}\\
    &= \frac{p(\theta^{*}|y_{1:T})}{p(\theta^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}{q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})}\\
   & = \frac{p(y_{1:T}|\theta^{*}}{p(y_{1:T}|\theta^{t}}\frac{\theta^{*}}{\theta{t}}\frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}{q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})
\end{align}
```

Comment: I get an error. It says `Runaway argument?
 \alpha &= \frac {p(θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T})}{p(θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}\ETC.` which basically means that you miss a closing brace somewhere.

Comment: the last line is missing the closing brace and also a number of closing parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brace was missing at the very end, just before `\end{align}`.

How did I find it? I rewrote the code in the following way, so as to have numerators and denominators under visual control

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B8}{\theta}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \alpha
  &= \frac{p(θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T})}
          {p(θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T})}
     \frac{q(θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*})}
          {q(θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t})}
  \\
  &= \frac{p(θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T})}
          {p(θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T})}
     \frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}{q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})}
     \frac{q(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T}^{t},θ^{t})}
          {q(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T}^{*},θ^{*})}\\
  &= \frac{p(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T},θ^{*})}
          {p(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T},θ^{t})}
     \frac{p(\theta^{*}|y_{1:T})}
          {p(\theta^{t}|y_{1:T})}
     \frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}{q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})}
     \frac{q(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T}^{t},θ^{t})}
          {q(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T}^{*},θ^{*})}
  \\
  &= \frac{p(\theta^{*}|y_{1:T})}
          {p(\theta^{t}|y_{1:T})}
     \frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}{q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})}
  \\
  &= \frac{p(y_{1:T}|\theta^{*}}
          {p(y_{1:T}|\theta^{t}}
     \frac{\theta^{*}}{\theta{t}}
     \frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}{q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})} % <---
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

and the missing brace (signalled here with `<---`) became apparent. After adding it, I run LaTeX with no error.

I'm not sure you want `align`, though, because numbering each line doesn't seem necessary. Anyway, you decide.

I also don't recommend to alternate between `θ` and `\theta`: it makes the typescript confuse and less readable.

[image]

Using `\mid` instead of `|` would perhaps make the thing less compact.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please always show a full document, not just a fragment

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 \alpha &= \frac{p(θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T})}{p(θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*})}{q(θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t})}\\
    &=  \frac{p(θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T})}{p(θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}{q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})}\frac{q(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T}^{t},θ^{t})}{q(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T}^{*},θ^{*})}\\
    &= \frac{p(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T},θ^{*})}{p(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T},θ^{t})}\frac{p(\theta^{*}|y_{1:T})}{p(\theta^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}{q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})}\frac{q(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T}^{t},θ^{t})}{q(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T}^{*},θ^{*})}\\
    &= \frac{p(\theta^{*}|y_{1:T})}{p(\theta^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}{q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})}\\
   & = \frac{p(y_{1:T}|\theta^{*}}{p(y_{1:T}|\theta^{t}}\frac{\theta^{*}}{\theta{t}}\frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}{q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Produces

```
Runaway argument?
 \alpha &= \frac {p(θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T})}{p(θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \align.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> cc460
         
?
```

due to mis-matched braces

adding some `}`  produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character θ (U+03B8)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

as by default you can not use Greek directly  use `\theta` for math Greek

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 \alpha &= \frac{p(\theta^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T})}{p(\theta^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(\theta^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|\theta^{*},x_{1:T}^{*})}{q(\theta^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|\theta^{t},x_{1:T}^{t})}\\
    &=  \frac{p(\theta^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T})}{p(\theta^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(\theta^{t}|\theta^{*})}{q(\theta^{*}|\theta^{t})}\frac{q(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T}^{t},\theta^{t})}{q(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T}^{*},\theta^{*})}\\
    &= \frac{p(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T},\theta^{*})}{p(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T},\theta^{t})}\frac{p(\theta^{*}|y_{1:T})}{p(\theta^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(\theta^{t}|\theta^{*})}{q(\theta^{*}|\theta^{t})}\frac{q(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T}^{t},\theta^{t})}{q(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T}^{*},\theta^{*})}\\
    &= \frac{p(\theta^{*}|y_{1:T})}{p(\theta^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(\theta^{t}|\theta^{*})}{q(\theta^{*}|\theta^{t})}\\
   & = \frac{p(y_{1:T}|\theta^{*}}{p(y_{1:T}|\theta^{t}}\frac{\theta^{*}}{\theta{t}}\frac{q(\theta^{t}|\theta^{*})}{q(\theta^{*}|\theta^{t})}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

- From your code fragment can be concluded that you use `unicode-math` package and compile document by XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.
- Error is caused as pointed out @Ulrike in her comment. In the MWE below are code lines with missing closing parentheses brace and   closing parenthesis are marked by `<---`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{unicode-math}


\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   & = \frac{p(θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T})}
             {p(θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T})} \frac{q(θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*})}
                                                 {q(θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t})}\\
    & = \frac{p(θ^{*},x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T})}
              {p(θ^{t},x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}
                                                 {q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})}\frac{q(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T}^{t},θ^{t})}
                                                                      {q(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T}^{*},θ^{*})}\\
    & = \frac{p(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T},θ^{*})}
             {p(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T},θ^{t})}\frac{p(\theta^{*}|y_{1:T})}
                                                {p(\theta^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}
                                                                            {q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})}\frac{q(x_{1:T}^{t}|y_{1:T}^{t},θ^{t})}
                                                                                                 {q(x_{1:T}^{*}|y_{1:T}^{*},θ^{*})}\\
    & = \frac{p(\theta^{*}|y_{1:T})}
             {p(\theta^{t}|y_{1:T})}\frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}
                                         {q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})}\\
   & = \frac{p(y_{1:T}|θ^{*})} % <--- )
            {p(y_{1:T}|θ^{t})} % <--- )
                                    \frac{θ^{*}}
                                         {θ(t)}\frac{q(θ^{t}|θ^{*})}
                                                         {q(θ^{*}|θ^{t})} % <--- }
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Compilation with LuaLaTeX gives:

[image]